# How to Convert Date '2022-12-01' to 'December 2022'

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Like the title asks, how do you convert Date '2022-12-01' to 'December 2022' in Microsoft SQL? Or vice versa, which one is easier? I'm trying to do an INNER JOIN between two data sources that use the different date formatting.

Comment: Best is to use `date` or `datetime` data type and not string data type to store the date value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select format(CAST('2022-12-01' AS DATE),'MMMM yyyy')
```